# Asymptotics of sequence of rational numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, dynamical-systems, constants

There is a simple sequence of rational numbers. It starts from $a_1=1$, and then
$$
 a_{n}=\begin{cases}
  a_{n-1}
  &\text{for even }n
 \\
  a_{n-1}-\frac1n a_{\frac{n-1}2}
  &\text{for odd }n
 \end{cases}.
$$
It seems that it converges to $0$ as
$$
 a_n\sim \frac{A}n,\ \ \ A=3.258891....
$$
Has anyone seen a sequence like this before? Any fast algorithm for the computation of $A$? Any expression for $A$ through known constants? Thanks for any links.

There are a few first elements
$$
 a_1=1,\ a_2=1,\ a_3=\frac23,\ a_4=\frac23,\ a_5=\frac7{15},\ a_6=\frac7{15}, ....
$$

---

**Update 27/08/2023.** Let me say a few words about the source of the problem. Suppose that at each time step, a particle generates one new particle with probability $p$ or stays alone with probability $1-p$, where $p\in\mathbb{U}(0,1)$ is the uniform random variable on the unit interval. Let $X_t$ be the number of particles at time $t\in\mathbb{N}$. At the beginning $X_1=1$ - one particle. Denote
$$
 \varphi_n:=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_t=n)}{\mathbb{P}(X_t=1)},
$$
$$
 \Phi(z)=\varphi_1z+\varphi_2z^2+\varphi_3z^3+...,
$$
$$
 F(z)=\int_0^z\Phi(\zeta)d\zeta.
$$
It can be shown that $F$ satisfies the functional equation with the initial conditions
$$
 \frac{F(z)-F(z^2)}{z-z^2}=\frac12F'(z),\ \ F(0)=F'(0)=0,\ \ F''(0)=1,
$$
which leads to the generating equation for $\varphi_n$ similar to that for $a_n$. It seems that the main part of the asymptotics for $\varphi_n$ is the following, see the Figure[image: difference between exact values and asymptotic]

At the moment, I still can not prove that the constant before $n$ is $1/2(1-\ln2)$. This problem is equivalent to the problem from the question above. However, if it is true then other terms in the asymptotics can be expressed through this first constant. If I have time then I will try to write all the details and put them in, e.g., arxiv - because it can be lengthy to put it here. I will add other problems related to branching processes in a random environment. Of course, the link to math.stackexchange.com will be added as well - everybody can see who (Tian Vlašić) suggested $1/(1-\ln2)$.

**Update 26/09/2023**
The power series coefficients $\varphi_n$ of $\Phi(z)$, defined above, satisfy
$$
 \varphi_{n}=\begin{cases}
  \frac{n+1}{n-1}\varphi_{n-1}
  &\text{for even }n
 \\
  \frac{n+1}{n-1}\varphi_{n-1}-\frac{4}{n-1} \varphi_{\frac{n-1}2}
  &\text{for odd }n
 \end{cases},
$$
which is similar to the functional equation for $a_n$. It seems that the first few asymptotic terms for $\varphi_n$ contain the linear growth and power law decaying coefficients multiplied by short-phase periodic factors of period $2$, $4$, $8$, etc., see the next Fig.
[[image: asymptotic terms up to the period <span class=]$8$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APnBQ.png)

However, the next asymptotic term contains a long-phase oscillation of exponential period, see the Fig.
[image]
Here,
$$
 \rho_{8n}=\frac{11\ln2-9}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+1}=\frac{19-31\ln2}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+2}=\frac{27-45\ln2}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+3}=\frac{\ln2-5}{4\ln2-2},
$$
$$
\rho_{8n+4}=\frac{11\ln2-9}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+5}=\frac{33\ln2-13}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+6}=\frac{19\ln2-5}{4\ln2-2},\ \ \ \rho_{8n+7}=\frac{\ln2-5}{4\ln2-2},
$$
and
$$
 \alpha=2.545364930374021...\pm10.75397517526887...\mathbf{i}
$$
is the root of
$$
 1-2^{\alpha}=-\frac12\alpha.
$$
As it is mentioned above, I still cannot prove that the primary constant is $1/(2-\ln4)$. As a bonus, there is, perhaps, an equivalent problem: is it true that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^1\int_{z_n^2}^1...\int_{z_3^2}^1\int_{z_2^2}^1\frac{2z_1}{1+z_1}\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{2z_k}{(1+z_k)(1-z_k^2)}dz_1dz_2...dz_n=1-\ln2?
$$
Some details are available in https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.13765

The link to this question and the explicit mention of the help made by Tian Vlašić with using of WolframAlpha is added to the arxiv version.

There is also a maybe relevant paper, where $1/1-\ln2$ appears in some context https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689501 but I did not read it carefully yet.

Comment: Is $A$ possibly $\frac{1}{1-\log 2}$?

Comment: Can you please include in the body the first few terms of the sequence?

Comment: Yes, it would be very nice if this constant is what you suggested. Super!

Comment: @TianVlašić How did you identify $\frac 1 {1-\log 2}$ ?

Comment: @Tian Vlašić notation $\log 2$ is ambiguous. You must mean $\ln 2$.

Comment: A simple search by Wolfram Alpha. And yes, @JeanMarie I meant ln(2).

Comment: There are various tools detecting possible closed forms for numbers , for example the inverse symbolic calculator.

Comment: @AAK How did you come up with such a sequence?

Comment: The initial problem is a limit-distribution of branching processes in a random environment:  at each time step a particle generates one or two particles with probabilities $r$ and $1-r$ respectively, where $r$ is uniform from $(0,1)$. One of the constants in the distribution of the number of particles over a large time is described by this sequence. This is a very rough description, many details are complex - I will write them later when I check them...

Comment: Maybe you should consider adding your sequence (the numerators and denominators) to the OEIS? I didn’t find anything relevant. If the sequence is important, i.e., if you describe the process in detail, it should be added. However, that would require a, say, mathematica program. Are you able to write such one?

Comment: OK, but I need to check many details. I will also add the link to this discussion.

Comment: Well, that was just a suggestion.

Comment: The ordinary generating function $A(x)$ of the sequence satisfies $$
\left[ {(1 - x)A(x)} \right]^\prime   = 1 - A(x^2 ).
$$ This equation is satisfied asymptotically as $x\to 1-0$ by $
 - \frac{1}{{1 - \log 2}}\log (1 - x)$. If this is the correct behaviour near $x=1$ and this singularity gives the dominant term in the asymptotics of $a_n$, then we indeed have $$a_n  \sim \frac{1}{{1 - \log 2}}\frac{1}{n}.$$ These are just some thoughts.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, the original problem on branching processes leads to $\frac{F(z)-F(z^2)}{z-z^2}=\frac12F'(z)$. The asymptotic $F(z)\sim C(1-z)^{-1}$ with constant $C$ is directly connected to the constant from the question.  This constant should be determined from $F(0)=F'(0)=0$ and $F''(0)=1$, since the equation for $F$ is homogeneous. While the equation you suggested is non-homogeneous, the constant before $\ln(1-x)$ should also be determined from initial data $A(0)$, $A'(0)$ I guess. At the moment, I do not know which problem is simpler: for the sequence, or for the functional equation.